# Installing multiple sun sails with galv pipe concreted into ground

Tags: concrete, outdoor

Want to use 1.5” galvanized poles concreted into ground with holes drilled near ends.  Frost line here is mere 24” so can I just concrete a 12’ pole into 2’ or do I have to use some kind of formula to determine how deep to install pole
I have 3 rectangular sun sails that will be attached.

Comment: 2' sounds to shallow, even 6' fence posts should be 3'  deep

Comment: Frost is one concern.  The force of the wind against the sails is the main concern.  2 feet of dirt will not give enough support against the wind.  The 1.5 inch pipes might also be not strong enough.  Each pound of wind force at ten feet will equal 10 pounds at ground level.

Comment: In case you're wondering how many pounds of force you can expect on your sail, [here's one calculator](https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Wind-Load) that will tell you. If you don't like those numbers, an internet search for "calculate force of wind against a surface" will bring up a dozen other calculators. (That just happened to be the first response - no endorsement or guarantee of accuracy.)

Comment: Will the poles be self supporting or will you use bracing wires/cables for extra support?

Comment: 1:3 is the usual ratio. Be aware that 1-1/2" pipe will be quite flexible at 10'. I have a 8' length supporting some patio string lights and it has quite a curve in it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing long 20ft metal poles in concrete around a football pitch](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/82698/installing-long-20ft-metal-poles-in-concrete-around-a-football-pitch)  There are several other similar questions, too.

Comment: This has to be a dupe, but holding up netting is far different than holding up a solid sail in terms of the stresses under even a light breeze.

Comment: Depends on your LAHJ. You can either cowboy it and see if it bends, breaks, or tears out of the ground (typically for places where your failure is unlikely to affect others - thus, rural, generally) or you install something designed to cope with the forces involved so it does not become a hazard to yourself or others (typically required in more built-up areas, and some rural areas.)

Answer (score 0):

If you make the footings wide enough 2' depth will work.

Poles for a shade sail will see significant sideways forces at the top (and thus toppling forces at the base) so you will need heavy footings.

So your for a good result your footings will be wide or deep or both. or pour a slab and bolt your poles to that.

Comment: This answer would be better if "wide enough" had a number attached. (My intuition is that it would have to be **really** wide.)

Comment: without knowing the number put on rectangular or the strength of the winds it needs to withstand, or being an engineer,  I'm not going to put a number on it.